# Chore schedule with fair distribution of pairs and groups

Tags: scheduling

I need to build a schedule that maps 7 people to 4 groups (3 pairs, 1 single) for each week.

An ideal schedule would be one where each person swaps pairs and groups in a round-robin style. If such a schedule is not possible, an algorithm that creates a schedule that minimizes repetition while being fair over the long term is enough.

A completely random schedule is my current fallback.

The closest problem to this that I found is the [round-robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament), but that only maps people to pairs and not pairs to groups.

#### Motivation

> I need to build a schedule for 7 flatmates and 4 types of chores so that everyone gets to work with everyone and swaps chores fairly.

Comment: You can enumerate all possibilities; assign each possibility to each week. Does that answer your question?

Comment: It's a possible solution, but not ideal, as nothing would stop a person to be assigned to the same group several times in a row.

Not sure how to call that property. Maybe I would say that such a solution would be fair **globally** (everyone gets the same amount and kind of work in the longterm), but not **locally** (someone might get the same kind of work in a row).